# Dolphin File manager List of devices disappeared

Tags: dolphin

While I was using Dolphin file manager, suddenly the list of devices disappeared while i was copy/pasting some files and the category itself called Devices. How do I bring this back?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured it out using this post. I needed to right click on any empty space on the left pane of the dolphin file manager then > Show all
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=224&t=151675